# Action must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I was trying make my react-native code prittier and I tried use Actions as new actions in following way:

**actions:**

```
import { Action } from "redux";

export const actionType = {
  INCREMENT_ACTION: "example/INCREMENT_ACTION",
  DECREMENT_ACTION: "example/DECREMENT_ACTION"
};

export class ExampleIncrementAction implements Action {
  type = actionType.INCREMENT_ACTION;
}

export class ExampleDecrementAction implements Action {
  type = actionType.DECREMENT_ACTION;
}

export type ExampleActions = ExampleIncrementAction | ExampleDecrementAction;
```

so reducer can looks like that:

```
export default function exampleReducer(
  state = initialState,
  action: ExampleActions
) {
  switch (action.type) {
...
```

But now the strange errors appear: When I try use action in following way:

```
const increment = () => ({ type: 'example/INCREMENT_ACTION' });
const decrement = () => new ExampleDecrementAction();

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => {
  return bindActionCreators({ increment, decrement }, dispatch);
};
```

calling the *increment* action is fine, but calling *decrement* action caused error: `Action must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.`

My question: **Is there a way to use new class object as action?** What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Redux by design only accepts plain objects as actions to avoid various possible mistakes. For example passing a Promise as an action.

> **Is there a way to use new class object as action?**

To use some class instances as actions you could either implement a custom middleware to overcome this limitation (this might lead to errors in future if someone say dispatches a Promise as action)

```
const useCustomActions = state => next => action => next({ ...action })
```

Or do it in action creator per action level

```
const decrement = () => ({...new ExampleDecrementAction()});
```